# coordinate (x,y) issue from a clic in the popup

Tags: java, javascript

I have a point (x, y) recover by clicking in a popup that contain an image(issue from a servlet that transform a pdf file to an image) of a pdf file,the problem is that I need to insert an image on the pdf file in the same position of he clic in the popup.
but the reference(x,y) is not the same for the popup and the pdf file.so when i clic in the top of popup i found the image in the bottom of the pdf file(the image is always shifted).
know i try to find a relation between the reference of the popup and the pdf file,but i dont know how.

Comment: This question is probably too broad to be answered.

You should answer at least answer these questions yourself to be helped:

Which tag is applicable, java or javascript?

How are you trying to insert the image?

How is the PDF generated?

You at least have to give us some code!

Comment: ok,i use javascript to display a popup that contain a image (image issue from a servlet that transform a pdf file to image), and then i use dwr to communique with a java function that insert an image in the position x,y issue from the clic in the popup